How to read heart rate from smart watches in real time? Second attempt
How do you get the heart rate signal from a smartwatch to a Flutter app running on a phone in real time? That is, with a delay of less than a second?
To narrow the scope a little, iOS only needs access to Apple Watch, while Android only needs access to Android Wearables.
Any advise would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

This question is similar to: How to read heart rate from smart watches in real time?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@TangentiallyPerpendicular Both questions are actually the same. But the original question was closed because it contained too much information. It's also marked for deletion, hence there's not much use of the original question.

Rather than posting a new question you should update the existing one so that it's a good fit for StackOverflow. Unsure why you think your question is marked for deletion, there are no delete-vote thus far.

I'm a bit confused. Is there any problem with the approaches you get when typing "smartwatch flutter heart signal in real-time" into a search engine?

The proper way to deal with having your question closed that does not violate site guidelines

I'll break answer up into Collection (getting heart rate data on the watch) and Communication (sending data from watch to Flutter app), and add links for WearOS
Collection

Determine whether you want spot collection of health data (only for a short amount of time) or constant background monitoring.
Follow the appropriate guide for declaring permissions, checking capabilities on the device, and then registering the type of data you want. E.g. this is the current guide for spot measurements, and this is the guide for monitoring data in the background

Communication

You can use either the Data API or Message API to communicate from WearOS device to phone. The former is more for keeping data in sync between devices, and the latter is more for one-off signaling. See this SO answer for more details.
You can search for flutter WearOS connectivity libraries, or you can use the guides specific for each platform. This is one library I found that implements the Message API for communicating with WearOS devices.

